# syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, syntax

I have the following code:

```
<%= form_tag(email_post_path, method: :put) %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:email) %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

and I get the error `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input` - why is that?

I tried setting `<%= end %>` but that didn't help either ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You forgot to add `do` with `form_tag`, it should look like this

```
<%= form_tag(email_post_path, method: :put) do %>
```